# Installing unofficial web app office

Tags: webapps

I've installed snap as instructed but when trying to install the office web app I get the following error:error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "unofficial-webapp-office" (31) (cannot find required base "core18")

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly which release of Ubuntu are you installing on top of?

Comment: I'm using 16.10

Comment: Do you have the `core18` snap installed? (see `snap list`)